# How to handle timeout with net/http in ruby while sending requests to IPs from given IP range and skip IPs with timeout and move to next ones?

Tags: ruby, timeout, ip, net-http

I want to handle timeout for IP range taken from console for which I make requests to IPs within taken range and getting timeout error.
I want to make requests to all IPs and get responses from them.
For IP that time out , want to skip it and move to next one. How to handle this so loop dont get exception and script sends request to all IPs that can give response handling timed out ones.

Attaching code here:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'ipaddr'

puts "Origin IP:"
originip = gets()
(IPAddr.new("209.85.175.121")..IPAddr.new("209.85.175.150")).each do |address|
  req = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://#{address.to_s}"))
  puts req
end
```

Error:

```
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `initialize': A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:53:in `timeout'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:379:in `get_response'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:356:in `get'
        from IP Range 2.rb:9
        from IP Range 2.rb:8:in `each'
```

Comment: rescue the exception?  It would also be nice if you could title your post in a way that describes the problem you are having, rather than the programming task that you are doing.  Your last 4 questions ask different things but all have effectively the same title.

Comment: I have tried to elaborate things I want to do, please tell if you want more details.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Marc says. You should rescue the exception. Like so:

```
begin
  response = Net::HTTP.get(...)
rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED => e
  # Do what you think needs to be done
end
```

Also, what you get back from the call to `get()` is a response, not a request.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the exception using [timeout](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html),

```
require 'timeout'

(IPAddr.new("209.85.175.121")..IPAddr.new("209.85.175.150")).each do |address|
  begin
    req = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://#{address.to_s}"))
    puts req
  rescue Timeout::Error => exc
    puts "ERROR: #{exc.message}"
  rescue Errno::ETIMEDOUT => exc
    puts "ERROR: #{exc.message}"
  # uncomment the following two lines, if you are not able to track the exception type.
  #rescue Exception => exc
  #  puts "ERROR: #{exc.message}"
  end
end
```

Edit: When we rescue `Timeout::Error`, only those exceptions which belongs to `Timeout::Error` class will be caught. We need to catch the raised exception using their error class, updated the code accordingly.

Comment: not able to jump to next IP address in given IP range after exception has been raised on console. Getting error like following ``C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `initialize': A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby``

Comment: @AkashPanchal add a next in the loop, and when one fails it goes to the next iterator item

Comment: Well I don't think there is a need of `next` statement. If the exception is properly handled, it should automatically go to next item in the loop.

Comment: Timeout: Ruby's Most Dangerous API:  http://www.mikeperham.com/2015/05/08/timeout-rubys-most-dangerous-api/